# External POST form through iframe

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to get a page which includes a POST form to load inside an iframe for users to be able to confirm an action such as deleting a listing. I have successfully got the JS and the form page to load inside the iframe, but when I click an action inside the form, it's not updating the listing. Instead, it just refreshes the page.

The form is working fine because if I try to access the `content-url` manually in the browser and update the form, it works fine.

How can I get the iframe content to refresh instead of the parent page and load the response inside the iframe itself? What I am doing wrong exactly?

Any help is appreciated!!

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<button class="myclass" content-url="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/?a_action=delete_auction&pid=<?php the_ID(); ?>">Delete Me</button>
               <div class="popup"><iframe id="mynewiframeid" name="myframename" src=""></iframe></div>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {      
  $(document).click(function(e) {
      if ($(".popup").is(":visible")) {
        $(".popup").fadeOut("fast")
      }
  });

 $(".myclass").click(function() {
      if (!$(".popup").is(":visible")) {
        $('#mynewiframeid').attr('src',$(this).attr('content-url'));
        $(".popup").fadeIn("slow");
      }
      return false;
  });

  $(".popup").click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
  })
 });
```

Form:

```
  <div class="popup_content"> 
            <h3> You are about to delete <b><?php echo $title; ?></b>!</h3>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['yes_confirm']))
            {
                $s = "update ".$wpdb->prefix."posts set post_status='trash' where id='$pid'";
                $wpdb->query($s);
                echo '<div class="deleted_item_ok">';
                printf(__('Your item has been deleted successfully!'));
                echo '</div>';
            }
            else
            {
    ?>
            <form method="post">
            <div class="are_you_sure_delete">
            <?php
            _e('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
            ?>
            </div>
 <button class="button-small button-w-green" type="submit" id="submits" name="yes_confirm">Yes, Delete</button>
 <button class="button-small button-w-red" type="submit" id="submits" name="no_confirm">No!</button>
            </form>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to replace html in the class "popup" with following js code..

```
HTML => <div class="popup"><iframe id="iframeid" src=""></iframe></div>
JS => $('.popup').html(response);
```

This replaces the iframe element in the HTML above with the response..! Therefore after response comes, no iframes inside the page..

If you do want to use an iframe, I don't think you have to deal with AJAX. Instead just change the src of iframe. You may use following js code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
      $(document).click(function(e) {
          if ($(".popup").is(":visible")) {
            $(".popup").fadeOut("fast")
          }
      });

     $(".myclass").click(function() {
          if (!$(".popup").is(":visible")) {
            $('#iframeid').attr('src',$(this).attr('content-url'));
            $(".popup").fadeIn("slow");
          }
          return false;
      });

      $(".popup").click(function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation()
      })
  });
```

[**Fiddle (with fake src urls)**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5nk2qpo/)

Comment: thanks! This makes complete sense.
Now, I need to figure out why the src is not getting set using the above script. Might be something to do with having the same button with the class="myclass" next to every item on that page and the iframe doesn't know which src URL to set.
Maybe need to add the getelementbyid somewhere?

Comment: I don't think having the same button with the class="myclass" will be a problem. Because the click function uses $(this) to get content-url, it always gets the content-url of the button you clicked...

Comment: Did you check the attribute "src" of iframe after clicking the button? Any js erros in the console?

Comment: No errors at all, it only shows as

<iframe id="iframeid" name="myframename" src=""></iframe>

that said, when I went on a page where I only have 1 post, the src loaded fine. Which makes me believe it's more to do with having multiple items on the same page (just different ID ofc).

Comment: As you changed your code, it should show id="mynewiframeid", not id="iframeid". shouldn't it? BTW I added a fiddle to the answer...

Comment: yes, I changed it yet again trying to fiddle with it, hence the change in the result. I will accept your answer as I believe the issue is with my html/php not the JS. I think this is wrong

content-url="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/?a_action=delete_auction&pid=<?php the_ID(); ?>"

Comment: I guess you have to put "echo" inside php code segments to print it.
ie. <?php echo the_ID()?>, <?php echo bloginfo('siteurl') ?>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, correct the following errors and then see if it works:

1. in your  you are missing semicolon after the closing parenthesis
2. you close the php tags and right after you continue with url and then you add another closing php tags
3. What you are looking for is this inside your content-url:

   `<?php bloginfo('siteurl') . '/?a_action=delete_auction&pid=' . $the_ID; ?>`

   4. What is the_ID()? I dont see that function. And if exists it has to return the value that you will store in variable $the_ID. You also have to call that function before button tag to get that variable.
   5. In your JS you need to wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function() {}`
   6. It seems you are trying to do GET request and not POST request since you are not sending any data in the body but in the url
   7. Missing semicolon at the end of first .click function
   8. I didn't even look at all other .click functions cause there's some repetitions going on and more weird stuff

Comment: The function is working fine. The
          `the_ID()`
is working fine as it's grabbing it the a query set inside a function earlier. The duplicate JS is a mistake as I was testing something else and forgot to remove it.
Thanks a lot for responding though!